# Where in Ubuntu can I locate the files to edit the css to create my own theme?

Tags: unity, 15.04, themes

In Advance: I apologize I am very new to Linux!

I am reading this documentation, everything seems pretty straight forward, however I do not know where to locate the files [shown in the example](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Unity/Theming).
Some people online say they exist in a .theme or .themes folder in the home directory, After ticking "view hidden folders" I do not find this folder - I only see it when i switch to Gnome and not when I'm using Unity. I am running Ubuntu 15.04

Comment: Make `.themes` if it doesn't exist. Copy a theme from `/usr/share/themes` as a starting point.

Comment: you can find all themes usually in /usr/share/themes where you will see all loaded themes and the css files are beneath respective theme's gtk* directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To edit the *.css files of your installed themes, browse to this folder

```
/usr/share/themes/nameofyourtheme/*
```

and look for the *.css files in the folders. But it is recommended to backup your themes before doing anything.

You might need root permision to edit the files.

Also, as [muru](https://askubuntu.com/users/158442/muru) said, it is better that you copy the files from the above location to `~/.themes`, then type the following command to change the permission of the folder, and finally edit the files:

```
cp -R /usr/share/themes/some-theme ~/.themes
```

Comment: As long as you don't use `sudo` to copy, you don't need to change the permissions. Definitely no need to make everything executable in any case.

Comment: @muru - then, what is the command to not make it executable and just remove the root permission, sorry am new to linux and also currently learning. please help.

Comment: Just do `cp -R /usr/share/themes/some-theme ~/.themes`.

Comment: Thanks guys much appreciated! So the .themes will just be a back up, or should i be using this as the main source for themes? Thanks

Comment: If you copy the themes to `.themes` it will be a backup no doubt but also, the edited themes here can also be set as your current theme in the tweak tools.